# Can I use the space of a dynamic array of some type to construct objects of other types?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, placement-new

can I use the memory of a dynamic array of integers with placement `new`?

```
int* p = new int[10]{};
std::string* pstr = new(p)std::string("Hi there");
std::cout << *pstr << std::endl;
pstr->~std::string();
delete[] p;
```

The code works fine but is it safe to do so? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, as written it's not safe, because you do not know for sure that `sizeof (std::string)` is <= `10 * sizeof (int)`.

If you add code to check for that then it's safe(r), something like:

```
size_t bytes_needed = sizeof (std::string);
size_t ints_needed = (bytes_needed + sizeof (int) - 1) / sizeof (int);
int *p = new int [ints_needed];
...
```

There might also be alignment issues however, so using [`aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) (and `free`) instead of `new []` (and `delete []`) is a better bet.

Comment: This is not a problem: https://godbolt.org/z/f41qhqWvo (even though all compilers are implementing Small String Optimalization) explanation why this is wrong is much more complex.

Comment: @MarekR I'm not saying it necessarily *is* a problem, I'm saying it *might be* a problem.  `sizeof (std::string`) is platform-dependent.

Comment: yes by you just scratching the surface, what can went wrong with it. In 99% of cases it will just work.

Comment: @MarekR So apart from alignment (which I have added to my answer), what else might go wrong?